# Verify a certificate chain in STACK_OF(X509)

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate, x509

So I have a certificate chain stored in STACK_OF(X509). 
This is what I did with it :

```
STACK_OF(X509) *chain = SSL_get_peer_cert_chain(ssl);

X509_STORE_CTX* newCert = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
if(newCert){
    X509_STORE_CTX_set_chain(newCert, chain);
    std::cout << X509_verify_cert(newCert) << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "ERROR : " << X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(newCert) << std::endl;
```

The issue is that the `X509_verify_cert(newCert)` returns -1 meaning the initialization of the `X509_STORE_CTX` was not down properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, this is related to [Use of STACK_OF(X509)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14848533/1741542).

You shouldn't copy only half of the source code at [apps/verify.c](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=apps/verify.c;h=893670ff41321317e7a057e0a8c3fd64cb7d048a;hb=46ebd9e3bb623d3c15ef2203038956f3f7213620). If you look deeper, you will find, among other lines,

```
 286         if(!X509_STORE_CTX_init(csc,ctx,x,uchain))
```

Comment: what does X509_STORE *store do? how to initialize that? And if I have a chain, should I really use the third parameter, an X509*?

Comment: I need to initialize all the certificates in ssl/certs into an x509_store and then use it to verify certificates in the stack_of(x509)?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan I'm not that familiar with openssl, but a quick look at the callers of `check` leads to `X509_STORE_new` and that leads to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646841/1741542 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756553/1741542. I think this is not a trivial task. You need to search and experiment a bit with the verify.c source.